# Woocommerce remplazar botón de Add to Car por Whatsapp

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Actualmente tengo un proyecto en woocommerce,  tengo que reemplazar el boton de Add to cart por un boton que al hacer clic se abra whatsapp.  Se puede hacer este cambio?  Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existen plugins para cambiar el botón de añadir al carrito, por un botón de Whatsapp. Mírate este enlace: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-whatsapp-order/

Comment: Este está vigente ya que el sugerido anterior, terminó su soporte el 25/09/19. https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-orders-on-whatsapp/22777816

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes utilizar algún tipo de Plug-in de Woocomerce que te permita personalizar el destino del botón "Add to cart" como por ejemplo éste (o alguno similar): https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-cart-redirect-to-checkout-page/ que está pensado en principio para redirigir desde dicho botón al checkout directamente, pero también puedes configurarlo para que redirija a un sitio web externo como en éste caso sería Whatsapp.